# Sunmi T2 - Flutter

Tags: flutter, printing, sunmi

I am using the sunmi_printer_t1mini for my sunmi T2 printer to print tokens, the printing seems to be going fine, but the token paper in not being cut, I checked if there is any function for cutting the paper but I couldn't find any, can anyone please help me with this.

Below I have attached my code which I run to print.

```
  _testPrint() {
    Log.print('Test Print');
    try {
      Printer.text("Printer OK!",
          styles: PrintStyle(
              bold: true, align: PrintAlign.center, size: PrintSize.mdd));
      Printer.text("Powered by Grapes IDMR",
          styles: PrintStyle(
              bold: true, align: PrintAlign.center, size: PrintSize.mdd));
      Printer.cutPaper();
    } catch (e, s) {
      Completer().completeError(e, s);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use

```
SunmiFlutterPrint.autoOutPaper();
```

not that this also should be imported:

```
import 'package:sunmi_flutter_print/sunmi_flutter_print.dart';
```